# Apache won't start with 2 or more VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have an OpenVZ VPS running Ubuntu 10.04, and a standard install of Apache2, PHP, the usual. I am trying to set up multiple hostname-based VHosts to allow all of my users to have access to some webspace, but when I define more than 1 VirtualHost entry in my httpd.conf, Apache will not start. Using 'service apache2 start' reports a failure, and 'apache2ctl start' runs fine, but apache isn't running after it finishes.

At the moment, I'm only trying to get 2 VHosts working, a real domain name, and a similar No-IP subdomain. Here is my httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainname.com
  ServerAlias *.domainname.com
  DocumentRoot /home/user1/www-pub
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
  CustomLog /home/user1/logs/access.log common
  ErrorLog /home/user1/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain.servegame.com:80>
  ServerName domain.servegame.com
  DocumentRoot /home/user2/www-pub
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
  CustomLog /home/user2/logs/access.log common
  ErrorLog /home/user2/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I missing something here? I've looked in the documentation, and as far as I can tell, everything should be working fine.

Comment: **ERROR LOG ERROR LOG ERROR LOG**

Comment: Where can I find this error log? The only logs I can find are the access and error logs for http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apache2ctl configtest`  will show you why it isn't working.

My guess is that you cannot resolve domain.servegame.com, or it resolves to an IP that isn't bound to a nic on your computer but that is only a guess,   Post the output of the configtest and we should be able to better help...

If you are only doing name based virtual hosting then change

`<VirtualHost domain.servegame.com:80>`

to

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

which will tell apache to listen on all ips.

You should also check the error log, which is in /var/log/apache2/ by default. Open it and look for anything related to your virtual host.

Comment: This is not the case, the configtest passes.
Also, changing that doesn't fix anything. :/

Regardless, here's the output:
'james@vps2:~$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 208.53.130.173 for ServerName
Syntax OK'

And yes, I know there's nothing at the IP, I'll add a redirect just as soon as I fix the VHost problem

Comment: well if the configtest passes, apache should start.   Look in the errorlog (same errorlog as http requests)  and it should have a line that says why it didn't start.

Comment: Well, I found it. The log directory for the second VHost was never created. Thanks for your help Doon!